# Notation for a binary relation depending on another set

Tags: graph-theory, notation, set-theory, relations

I am new to binary relations and graph theory, and I have actually not written math equations for quite some time...
Is the following notation correct ?

$R_E$ is a binary relation between edges from $E$ and edges from $E'$.
It is based an on a binary relation $R_V$ between vertices.
$R_E$ includes edges that link vertices that are related through $R_V$.

$$\begin{equation}
R_E =  \left\{ \{ e, e' \} \left| 
\begin{array}{l}
    e \in E, e' \in E',\\
    \phi(e) = \{ v_1, v_2 \}, \\
    \phi'(e') = \{ v_1', v_2' \}, \\
    \{ \{ v_1, v_1' \}, \{ v_2, v_2' \} \} \subset R_V \\
    \lor \{ \{ v_1, v_2' \}, \{ v_2, v_1' \} \} \subset R_V
\end{array} 
\right.
\right\}
\end{equation}$$

Is it mathematically correct, and is it graphically correct (with big braces and a big line) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually binary relations are *ordered* pairs: $(e, e')$ rather than unordered pairs $\{e, e'\}$; this allows for the possibility of the relation being asymmetric, and in the case of a relation between $E$ and $E'$ it is much easier to define $R_E$ as a subset of $E \times E'$.

Aside from that, your notation is perfectly correct...

...and a terrible idea, because if you're expressing a thought that complicated, it's better to write it out in words, rather than in symbols. Unless you're an actor playing a mathematician in a movie, the point is to be understood, rather than write an impressive formula, and so I would just write

> $R_E$ is a binary relation between $E$ and $E'$; an edge $e \in E$ is related to an edge $e' \in E'$ if the two endpoints of $e$ are related via $R_V$ to the two endpoints of $e'$ (in some order).

Comment: Thank you for your answer; Can I introduce $R_E$ with the equation $R_E = \{ (e, e') \mid e \in E, e' \in E' \}$ and explain the relation with $R_V$ with words ? Or is it incorrect or considered as a bad practice to split the information that way ?

Comment: We can split the information, but what you wrote is incorrect, because $R_E$ is not **all** of $\{(e,e') \mid e \in E, e' \in E'\}$. Rather, you should say $R_E \subseteq \{(e,e') \mid e \in E, e' \in E'\}$ and then explain the rest with words. Equivalently, we already have notation for this set: you can write $R_E \subseteq E \times E'$.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer by Misha suggest that you can write as follows.
$R_E =\left\{ ( e, e')\mid e \in E, e' \in E'\right\}$; Also given that $\phi(e) = ( v_1, v_2 ), \phi'(e') = (v_1', v_2' ),\{ ( v_1, v_1' ), (v_2, v_2' ) \} \subset R_V \text{ and }\{ ( v_1, v_2' ), (v_2, v_1' )\} \subset R_V.$

Comment: Again, I must stress that you should begin with $\subseteq$ and not $=$. What you're doing is like saying "All Europeans are French; specifically, Europeans living in France are French." By the end, you've given the definition, but it's not good that you begin with a false statement.

Comment: A binary relation can also be denoted by an unordered pair if the relation symmetric.

Comment: Yes, but that's not the part of your statement that I take issue with.